# PictureBox image does not shrink, but PictureBox itself expand to fit the image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

When I add a picturebox to the form at runtime, the picturebox acts exactly like I want. But when I add it to the panel, the pictureBox expands to fit the image.

Below is the code:

```
private PictureBox globalPicBox = (PictureBox)null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.globalPicBox = new PictureBox();
    this.globalPicBox.Name = "a";
    this.globalPicBox.Tag = (object)"a";
    this.globalPicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    this.globalPicBox.Top = 50;
    this.globalPicBox.Left = 50;
    this.globalPicBox.Height = 100;
    this.globalPicBox.Width = 100;
    this.globalPicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\Photo.jpg");
    this.globalPicBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.globalPicBox.AutoSize = true;
    this.panel1.Controls.Add((Control)this.globalPicBox);
}
```

What is the problem? And why?

Comment: hint, not about the question: All cast`s in your code (`(PictureBox), (object), (Control)`), are Unnecessary

Comment: I've run your code and it works correctly - the picture box stays 100x100px and squashes my picture down. Perhaps you adjust the picture box somewhere else in your code to be docking or change the `AutoSize` or `SizeMode`?

Comment: I checked it out as well and it worked fine. What are the properties of your panel?

Comment: Same here... works just like it should.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `Dock` property?

Comment: I did `AutoSize = true`.

Comment: When you use `AutoSize = true`, you're saying "resize the PictureBox to be the same size as the image", not "resize the image to fit the picture box". You actually want AutoSize to be *false*. The resize mode of the image inside is handled by `SizeMode`, as you have correctly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit ... set `globalPicBox.AutoSize = false` and it'll work.
If it doesn't please check the rest of your code for changes to `globalPicBox`'s `AutoSize, SizeMode and Dock` parameters and hopefully you'll find your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Simple Just Set `globalPicBox.SizeMode=Strech`
The image will shrink or stretch to meet the picturebox size and your picture box will not expand or shrink it will remain the same size